# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 (\tan^2 x + \cot^2 x)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> **How to integrate** $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 (\tan^2 x + \cot^2 x)} \,dx$$

Let $z = e^{ix}$. We write the Fourier series
$$
\frac1{\tan^2x+\cot^2x} = \frac1{\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{i(z+z^{-1})}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{i(z+z^{-1})}{z-z^{-1}}\right)^2}
$$

$$
= -\frac1{\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^2}
$$

$$
= -\frac{(1+z^2)^2(1-z^2)^2}{(1-z^2)^4+(1+z^2)^4}
$$

$$
= -\frac{(1-z^4)^2}{2(1+6z^4+z^8)}
$$

$$
= -\frac12 + \frac{4z^4}{1+6z^4+z^8}
$$

$$
= -\frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2[1+(3-2\sqrt2)z^4]} - \frac1{\sqrt2[1+(3+2\sqrt2)z^4]}
$$

$$
= -\frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt2[1+(3-2\sqrt2)z^4]} - \frac{(3-2\sqrt2)z^{-4}}{\sqrt2[1+(3-2\sqrt2)z^{-4}]}
$$

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an even function that is continuous and $\pi$-perioidic, then $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \csc^{2}(x) f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ if the integral on the left converges.  This becomes a [Lobachevsky integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula) when $f(x) = \sin^{2}(x) g(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the [Lobachevsky integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula)

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 (\tan^2 x + \cot^2 x)} \,dx\\
=& \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\cdot\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^4x+1}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^4x+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Comment: Really quick and easy